# DiscordPY error, trouble finding command author

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm having trouble figuring out how to find the author of a message from a command in discordpy, I've read up on the documentation and simply can't figure out the problem. I've tried various things and none of them have seemed to work so would really appreciate some advice on this, thanks! The problem recieved is "Context" Object has no attribute "lower", which I don't understand, since the .lower() is referring to state

```
    @client.command(pass_context=True)
    async def swear(state, ctx):
        global filtertext
        if state.lower() == "off" and (ctx.author.id) in Admins and filtertext != []:
            filtertext=[]
            status = False
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use the commands extension, it requires ctx as the first variable.

You just need to switch the state and ctx.

```
async def swear(ctx, state)
```

Also be aware that this only takes in the first word after your command.
To take in more than 1 word,

```
async def swear(ctx, *, state)
```

Also, I recommend joining the DiscordAPI server, since they can help you much quicker than stackexchange.

Comment: Thanks so much :) Your second comment helped me out with another problem I had :)

Comment: Please leave an answer and upvote if this helped you out! Thank you.